# Cargar valores de elemento <select> con ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

No tengo idea de como cargar un `select` después de crearlo dinámicamente dentro de una tabla con AJAX.  Ésta es la llamada AJAX:

```
function LoadMarcas(id) {
    $("#MarcasResult tbody tr").remove();  
    $.get(_urlBase + "Ofertas/GetMarcasUser?id=" + id, null, DataBind);
    function DataBind(MarcaList) {
        var SetData = $("#SetMarcasTemp");        
        for (var i = 0; i < MarcaList.length; i++) {
            var Data = "<tr class='row_" + MarcaList[i].DetalleOfertaTempId + "'>" +
                "<td>" + MarcaList[i].Marca + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + MarcaList[i].RegistroSanitario + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + MarcaList[i].TitularRegistro + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + MarcaList[i].Origen + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + MarcaList[i].Fabricante + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + "<a href='#' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' onclick='EditMarcaTemp(" + MarcaList[i].DetalleOfertaTempId + ")'  title='Editar'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a> <a href='#' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' onclick='DeleteMarca(" + MarcaList[i].DetalleOfertaTempId + ")'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>" + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + "<select id='selectedit' class='form-control'></select>" + "</td>" +
                "</tr>";
            GetCatalogoProveedores($('#selectedit'));
            SetData.append(Data);            
        }        
    }   
}
```

Ahora lo que quiero es cargar en ese `select` los registros con la siguiente función:

```
function GetCatalogoProveedores(element) {
    if (Titulares.length == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            //url: '../Ofertas/GetTitularesRegistro',
            url: _urlBase + "Ofertas/GetTitularesRegistro",
            success: function (data) {
                Titulares = data;
                RenderGetCatalogoProveedores(element);
            }
        })
    }
    else {

        RenderGetCatalogoProveedores(element);
    }
}

function RenderGetCatalogoProveedores(element) {
    var $ele = $(element);
    $ele.empty();
    $ele.append($('<option/>').val('0').text('Selecciona una opción'));
    $.each(Titulares, function (i, val) {
        $ele.append($('<option/>').val(val.MtoProveedorId).text(val.RazonSocial));
    })
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `Titulares` y dónde se asigna? ¿Has probado a depurar el códio o intentar seguir el orden de ejecución para ver qué es lo que está haciendo exactamente y por dónde se va?

Comment: Titulares es una variable de tipo